# How to remove time from object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, datetime, properties

I am trying to remove time from one of property in my object. Actually I check with : index, if timestamp is present in property value or not. Actually I have this

input

```
[
  {
    "S": "Charge Interest Against Past Due Account",
    "C": "Mon Apr 13 10:38:05 GMT 2015"
  },
  {
    "S": "Charge Interest Against Past Due Account",
    "C": "Mon Apr 13 10:35:05 GMT 2015"
  }
]
```

output

```
[
  {
    "S": "Charge Interest Against Past Due Account",
    "C": "Mon Apr 13  2015"
  },
  {
    "S": "Charge Interest Against Past Due Account",
    "C": "Mon Apr 13  2015"
  }
]
```

Javascript

```
var object = ary.map(function(o){
    var result={}
   // console.log(o)
    for(i in o){
        console.log(i+":"+o[i]) ;
        if(o[i].indexOf(":")!=-1){
            console.log("timestam present")
        }
    }
})
```

The original array should remain unchanged, and result should be captured in separate array.

Here is the link to fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var ary=[
  {
    "S": "Charge Interest Against Past Due Account",
    "C": "Mon Apr 13 10:38:05 GMT 2015"
  },
  {
    "S": "Charge Interest Against Past Due Account",
    "C": "Mon Apr 13 10:35:05 GMT 2015"
  }]

ary.map(function(o){
        var d = new Date(o.C);
        o.C = d.toDateString();
})
console.dir(ary)
```

**OUTPUTS**

```
C: "Mon Apr 13 2015"
S: "Charge Interest Against Past Due Account"

C: "Mon Apr 13 2015"
S: "Charge Interest Against Past Due Account"
```

**UPDATE**

To retain the original object and get result in other object use following code.

```js
var ary=[
  {
    "S": "Charge Interest Against Past Due Account",
    "C": "Mon Apr 13 10:38:05 GMT 2015"
  },
  {
    "S": "Charge Interest Against Past Due Account",
    "C": "Mon Apr 13 10:35:05 GMT 2015"
  }]

var a = ary.map(function(o){
        var result = {};
        var d = new Date(o.C);
        result.S = o.S;
        result.C = d.toDateString();
        return result;
})
console.dir(a)
```

Comment: this way you could change the date format anytime later if you want.

Comment: your consoling wrong variable. log variable `ary` itself as it contains the desired output

Comment: why  a is undefiend I need  make in different array

Comment: I need to create different array and add different different value of date. and input array remain same

Comment: I don't want to change my input arry ..need to create new array

Comment: ok, so you want to retain original object get a changed one.. updated the answer..check out..

Answer (score 1):

You can split the `C` property by a space, then rejoin the parts you want to keep. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    var dateValues = ary[i].C.split(' ');
    ary[i].C = dateValues[0] + ' ' + dateValues[1] + ' ' + dateValues[2] + ' ' + dateValues[5]    
};
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/18hk1ksn/2/)

Alternative without the ugly string concatenation:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    var dateValues = ary[i].C.split(' ')
    dateValues.splice(3, 2);
    ary[i].C = dateValues.join(' ');   
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to parse the date into a Date object, and then reformat it. You can format it however you like, with or without the time. There are many libraries available for formatting dates. You stated that you were using jQuery, there is a plugin for date formatting.

I would not recommend you attempt to break the string up into fragments. There are many date formats ( you don't specify where this date comes from) and your solution can easily stop working in the future.

Comment: I was going to do it this way but the issue is the shortname for the Day at the start of the Date. JS has no method of doing this natively, so you would need to keep an array yourself containing the daynames to match up to the dayofweek value. Certainly not impossible, but definitely not pretty - especially if multiple languages are involved. The format of the date looks proprietary so I would image the OP already has control of that.

Comment: I'm always worried about maintenance costs; this is a perfect example of something which would be code buried deep and which works for a year, and which would then break because of somebody else's changes.

Comment: I also suggested the use of jquery dateFormat, given that the OP is already using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ary = [
{
"S": "Charge Interest Against Past Due Account",
"C": "Mon Apr 13 10:38:05 GMT 2015"
},
{
"S": "Charge Interest Against Past Due Account",
"C": "Mon Apr 13 10:35:05 GMT 2015"
}];
for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i++) {
    ary[i].C = ary[i].C.replace(/\d+:\d+:\d+\s*GMT\s*/g, '');
}
console.info(ary);
```

Comment: Note that OP is looking to remove the `GMT` as well.